# Rails application with heroku scheduler can have trouble with free dyno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sleep, scheduler

So i have a Rails application running on heroku with free dyno. I have a heroku scheduler working, and daily at midnight i want to perform some tasks.

My question is, since i have a free application, when the application sleeps can i have problems with the scheduler?

Basically, if my application is sleeping around midnight will the scheduler still do it's job? Or do i have to pay for a better service on heroku in order to stop this sleep time?

I have tried to research about it, but could not find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku documentation only mention that worker only dyno will never sleep (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping). Pay attention that in this configuration, your worker can eat all your free tier.

I understand that your worker is bundled with a web application. In that case, your Dyno can felt asleep (if there is no web traffic for 30min) and will only be awoken by the next web request it receives.

Answer (score 2):

So I get in touch with heroku support and they confirmed that sleeping dynos will not affect the scheduler which uses "one-off" dynos

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping

Also yesterday my task ran with no problems, and my application was asleep.